# How do I drive Eclipse from outside of Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I would like a few external tools to be able to monitor events within Eclipse and possibly launch events within it.  For example, I would like to be able to monitor the progress of a workspace rebuild, and I would like to be able to launch an Eclipse run configuration.

Does Eclipse provide any sort of API for this?

Answer (score 1):

You'll definitely need to write your own plugin. I suggest you start looking at these interfaces in the Eclipse API:

- [Interface IProgressMonitor](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor.html)
- [Interface ILaunchConfiguration](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/debug/core/ILaunchConfiguration.html)